# Any practical uses of inverse uniform distribution?

Tags: distributions, references, uniform-distribution

To motivate a paper in game-theory I need examples of real-life uses of the **inverse** uniform distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Inverse_uniform_distribution). Which type of physical, biological, financial, or social phenomena can be described/modeled by this distribution? Any references?

Comment: Why do you "need" real-life examples? Is this for homework? If so, you should add the `self-study` tag to your question. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe I have research level work that uses the inverse uniform and it would be nice to have few lines in the introduction motivating its use as many are not familiar with it. I was hoping applied folks here would have many examples. I wish it was for homework: will assign it to my students next semester.

Comment: If the _volume_ of gas in a canister has a Uniform distribution, then presumably the _pressure_ of the gas would have an inverse Uniform distribution, since pressure and volume are inversely proportional (Boyle's Law). [ Better check the fine points with a physics guru - been some time since I played with the real world :) ]

Comment: One possibility would be to think about a probability p drawn uniformly on [0, 1]. The mean of a geometric RV with parameter p is 1/p, so you'd have an inverse uniform distribution on the expectation of your geometric RV. Not sure what real-life process this describes, but maybe someone can think of a cool example.

Answer (score 1):

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution)  which says that *Inverse distributions arise in particular in the Bayesian context of prior distributions and posterior distributions for scale parameters*, but I do not know and didn't find any specific examples with the uniform distribution.

In the comments there are some examples but they do not seem very compelling.